# File path search

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, c++builder

I need to find all the occurences of a file "Test.TXT" in c:\ or any directory specified by user.
I need to do this in embarcadero c++.

The end result is that I need the paths of all the files.

Comment: Try [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`System.SysUtils.FindFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) and [`System.SysUtils.FindNext`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindNext) to search for any occurences of a file.

Comment: Would it also help in finding inside a folder? Like c:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Test.txt ? Or would I need to identify if that is a directory separately?

Comment: Yes, it works for directories too.